# Flutter Firebase Initialization: PlatformException(null-error) on Android

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I am working on a Flutter app for Android and encountering issues initializing Firebase. Despite following standard setup procedures, I keep receiving an error when running my app.

Error Description:
When I start the app, I get the following error message:

> Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(null-error, Host platform returned null value for non-null return value., null, null)

This occurs during the call to Firebase.initializeApp()

in my main function:

```
void main() async { 
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(); 
  await Firebase.initializeApp(); 
  final Database db = await initDatabase(); 
  runApp(WuupCirclesApp(db: db)); 
}
```

Development Environment:

- Flutter Version: [77.1.2]
- Dart Version: 231.9409
- Firebase Core Version: 2.24.2
- Android Studio Version: Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 | Build #AI-231.9392.1.2311.11076708
- Operating System: macOS

Steps Taken So Far:

- Verified and placed google-services.json in the android/app directory.
- Added Firebase dependencies in pubspec.yaml and ran flutter pub get.
- Checked configuration in android/build.gradle and android/app/build.gradle. - Ran flutter clean and restarted the app.
- Verified the package name in google-services.json and build.gradle.

Additional Information:

- The app is primarily developed for Android.
- Using the google_maps_flutter plugin.

What could be causing the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to change the initialization line of code to this:

```dart
await Firebase.initializeApp(
  options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
);
```

See step 4 in the [official documentation for Android platform](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=android#initialize-firebase).

Comment: thank a lot. i'm a beginner and i have a lot to learn and to know where to look.

Comment: @schnippeduudl did it work? If yes, consider marking this as an answer ;)

Comment: yes, thank you. i had to add e separate .dart-File for the class but your answer helped a lot